# Convert a character column to dates in R

Tags: r, date, format, date-conversion, as.date

I am trying to convert a data column (x_date) that has this form "31.03.2013" (the class is "character") into Dates in the form of "2013-01-31"

I tried with the following codes:

```
as.Date(x_date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
as.Date(x_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
as.Date(x_date,format= "%Y-%m-%d", tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d", "%d.%m.%Y"), optional=FALSE )
```

in all of the three cases the complete data column turns into "NA".
Then I tried this code:

```
format.Date(x_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

and I get an error warning.

Can anybody help me to convert my column into the respective Dates?

Comment: Your third option should have worked if you use `as.Date(x_date, format = '%d.%m.%Y')`

Comment: thank you for the helpful comment, it worked now!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `format` of the data instead of in `tryFormats`

```
as.Date(x_date, format = '%d.%m.%Y')
```